# how can I distinguish between the right and left mouse click on a selectionchanged event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a TreeListView with a SelectionChanged event handler.  When the selection is changed, I would like to know if the selection was changed with the right mouse click versus the enter key or the left mouse click.

Comment: MSDN doesn't have a page about `TreeListView.SelectionChanged` but it does have a page about `TreeView.SelectedItemChanged`. Is this what you actually have?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to directly from that Event's `EventArgs`. You could register on the `MouseUp` event for that control and then store it so that you can reference this information from the `SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: But reset the flag in the end of `SelectionChanged`. Also, problem is what if user right-clicks current selection, and then changes selection with left-click, or keyboard. Must reset the flag in `MouseUp` for mouse and `KeyUp` for keyboard, but only for keys that can change the selection (up, down, pgup, pgdn, home, end, maybe space, maybe letters...)

Comment: This is a good idea, but there is another problem: if the selectionchanged event never fires, then the flag is not set back to false.  This can happen for example if an item is selected first and then right clicked.